# how to combine pytest patch and capsys on the same test?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest, patch

Currently i have a similar function:

```
def mark_config(device):
    args = ['command','device','args']
    result = P_open(args)
    if result != 0:
        print('Error, config could not be marked')
    print('Success, config was marked')

def P_open(args):
    foo = Popen(args)
    foo.communicate()
    return foo.returncode # this is either 0 or some other integer, 0 for a success and anything else for a failure
```

for my first test i am mocking the output of "P_open" to be a failure, that part works fine however since "mark_config" is not actually returning anything rather it prints something out, this approach will not work.

```
@patch('test_file.P_open', return_value=1)
def test_mark_config_deployed_failed(mock_obj):
   expected_output = "Error, config could not be marked"
   device = 'test-device'
   result = mark_config(device)
   assert result == expected_output
```

for my second test i am using the "capsys" fixture to capture the output of the print statement, that part works fine however since i cannot manipulate the output of "P_open" i cannot simulate different output based on "args".

```
def test_mark_config_deployed_success(capsys):
   expected_output = "Success, config was marked"
   device = 'test-device'
   mark_config(device)
   out, err = capsys.readouterr()
   assert out == expected_output
```

i have tried something like the below, but that fails (fixture 'mock_obj' not found).

```
@patch('test_file.P_open', return_value=1)
def test_mark_config_deployed_failed(capsys, mock_obj):
   expected_output = "Error, config could not be marked"
   device = 'test-device'
   result = mark_config(device)
   out, err = capsys.readouterr()
   assert out == expected_output
```

I want to somehow combine both of these approaches (capsys, patch) so i can have one single approach to thes the above function, any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: try reordering the parameters (put capsys last)

Comment: that worked, thanks!